# Car presenter tests

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I caught a whiff of a code-smell emanating from one of my tests, in a scenario akin to the following:

```
[TestFixture]
public void CarPresenterTests{

    [Test]
    public void Throws_If_Cars_Wheels_Collection_Is_Null(){
         IEnumerable<Wheels> wheels = null;
         var car = new Car(wheels);
         Assert.That(
         ()=>new CarPresenter(car),
         Throws.InstanceOf<ArgumentException>()
         .With.Message.EqualTo("Can't create if cars wheels is null"));
    }
}

public class CarPresenter{
    public CarPresenter(Car car)
    {
        if(car.Wheels == null)
            throw new ArgumentException("Can't create if cars wheels is null");
        _car = car;
        foreach(var wheel in _car.Wheels)
        {
            wheel.Rolling += WheelRollingHandler;
        }
    }
}
```

I was struggling to describe what the problem is except that it seems wrong that a `CarPresenter` should attempt to dictate to a `Car` whether or not its `Wheels` are initialised correctly.

I wondered what pointers people here might give me?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Is a car really a car without wheels?

If not, the check should be done at `Car` **construction time** and `CarPresenter` should not have to check for null, it should assume that a good working car is passed to it. (Correction, `CarPresenter` should check  at construction time that `Car` is not `null`.)

Assuming of course that `Car` is a class that you control as well therefore you can change it.

And while we are talking about smells... You do not have much encapsulation. `Wheels` on `Car` should probably be private with public accessor methods if needed.

**Answer to comment:**

> So would you just handle the event
>   Wheels.Rolling event and accept that
>   if Wheels is null an exception will be
>   thrown

No, if you check at construction time and make sure you have working wheels, then you do not need to worry about it later. It is a lot better to bluntly (runtime exception) point out as early as possible if someone made a mistake (passing `null` for wheels) than waiting for these wheels to blow up who knows where in the code.

Comment: thanks for your answer.  So would you just handle the event Wheels.Rolling event and accept that if Wheels is null an exception will be thrown, or should car have a Moving event to encapsulate Wheels.Rolling, also, re encapsulation I'm working in C# so Wheels is a readonly property i.e. get_Wheels() with no set_Wheels(...) method.

Comment: @panamac: see answer body. Also, I never worked with C# or events before so I cannot comment on the second half of your question.

Answer (score 2):

First off - I do not like the idea of asserting on an exception message. I'd rather have the class throw a `WheelNotFoundException` rather than an `ArgumentException`. This could be easily asserted on.

Secondly, the smell I see are from the class itself:

1. As @c_maker pointed out, the check for existence of wheels should be done while creating a `Car`. It is not the `CarPresenter`'s responsibility to check if the car is valid. Besides, the `CarPresenter` takes a `Car` as a parameter - this contract itself should tell the `CarPresenter` that the `Car` is properly created.
2. Again a bit of violation of encapsulation - `CarPresenter` should deal with just the `Car` object, and not access its member's properties directly. In this case I'd rather have a `Car.OnMove` event handled at `CarPresenter` and in `Car` class should chain the event to the Wheel's rolling.
3. Car has `Wheel`s which is a collection of `Wheel`. Are you looking at a generic event handler for the `Wheel`s collection? I would prefer each `Wheel` having its own event.

Comment: It's true the class smells too, but actually since the test came first, the smell is more of a brain smell than a code smell.  Thanks to all answerers for the brain surgery.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, by passing wheels in the constructor, you are saying its public interface has something to do with giving it wheels.  Meaning anything that makes cars might give the wrong input.

Encapsulate building of cars:

```
builder = new CarBuilder();

var car = builder.Car().Wheel().Wheel().Wheel().Wheel().SteeringWheel().AsCar();
```

You could even make wheel factories and such for different types of wheels.